# Unit testing controller method property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, casting, controller, viewresult

I'm working through Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 by Apress and am trying to understand the syntax used in unit testing a particular controller method.

Given a controller method for a class `SomeController`:

```
public ViewResult List(int someInt) {

  ViewModel model = new ViewModel {
    ModelObject = new ModelObject {
      ObjectProperty = someInt;
    }
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

the unit test looks something like this:

```
[test method]
Some_Test () {

   //...some code here to set up a mock object named 'mock'

   SomeController target = new SomeController(mock.Object);

   //This next line is where the syntax is confusing me
   int result = ((ViewModel)target.List(1).Model).ModelObject.ObjectProperty;

   Assert.AreEqual(result, 1);
}
```

It's almost like the `ViewResult.Model` is having to be sort of 'cast' as type `ViewModel` or something. I'm sure there's a name for this syntax/technique and I'd like to learn more about what's going on here.

Is this technique required because something like:

```
 int result = target.List(1).Model.ModelObject.ObjectProperty;
```

doesn't work to be able to access the properties of the `model` object passed to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple cast embedded into the method chain.  `target.List(int)` returns a [`ViewResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  [`ViewResult.Model`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase.model%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is typed as an `Object` so that any model type can be used.  Casting it to your `ViewModel` type in your test is necessary to tell the compiiler what type `Model` is.  It's the equivalent of:

```
ViewModel model = (ViewModel)target.List(1).Model;
int result = model.ModelObject.ObjectProperty;
```

Comment: So clearly I haven't done a lot of object type casting (as evidenced by my noob question about such a basic construct). Thanks for the clear answer DS. It makes perfect sense now.